How to view Audio and Video of an on-going RTMP stream?
I have looked, and may be missing this question if it already has been asked.
It is possible to view the video/audio (or audio alone) in a RTMP stream. The workflow goes as follows:
Video Encoder -> ASR Cloud Captioning Platform -> Final Destination Platform.
The ASR Cloud service is using the RTMP Push method of giving the Video Encoder a URL and Key to stream to. Then using the URL and Key from the Final Destination it sends the stream, with the closed captions.
What I am seeing is if anyone knows how to grab, or pull, the RTMP stream audio before it gets sent out to the Final Destination? The purpose of this is to give the audio to a 3rd Party so they can transcribe.
I have tried to send the ASR Cloud URL to VLC with no avail. The error code basically comes down to "unknown".
I also cannot have the ASR Cloud send the stream to a broadcaster, like OBS or Restream, due to the latency of audio vs. captions. Once the Final Destination receives the stream it needs to receive the closed captions within two seconds.
Thank you for any help!
